# using d3.js with aurelia framework

Tags: javascript, d3.js, aurelia, systemjs

I'm trying to use d3.js with aurelia.io ,

I found a skeleton here, but it is outdated https://github.com/shmendo/aurelia-d3-skeleton

I installed it with jspm and about 20 differents packages are installed

```
jspm install d3
```

is there a way to install only one big package because I have issue while importing

I am able to import d3 like this

import * as d3 from 'd3';

but calling the time module cause an error on page load

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

aurelia-logging-console.js:54 ERROR [app-router] Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://host/d3-time.js
Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://host/d3-time.js
```

No idea why, my config.js file seems configured correctly to map d3-time

```
    System.config({
      baseURL: "/",
      defaultJSExtensions: true,
      transpiler: "babel",
      babelOptions: {
        "optional": [
          "runtime",
          "es7.decorators",
          "optimisation.modules.system"
        ]
      },
      paths: {
        "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
        "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
      },

      map: {
        "aurelia-bootstrapper": "npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.0",
        "babel": "npm:babel-core@5.8.38",
        "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.38",
        "core-js": "npm:core-js@1.2.7",
        "d3": "npm:d3@4.2.2",
        "socket.io-client": "npm:socket.io-client@1.4.8",
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0": {
          "assert": "npm:assert@1.4.1"
        },
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0": {
          "buffer": "npm:buffer@3.6.0"
        },
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1": {
          "events": "npm:events@1.0.2"
        },
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-http@1.7.1": {
          "Base64": "npm:Base64@0.2.1",
          "events": "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1",
          "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
          "stream": "github:jspm/nodelibs-stream@0.1.0",
          "url": "github:jspm/nodelibs-url@0.1.0",
          "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0"
        },
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-https@0.1.0": {
          "https-browserify": "npm:https-browserify@0.0.0"
        },
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0": {
          "path-browserify": "npm:path-browserify@0.0.0"
        },
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2": {
          "process": "npm:process@0.11.9"
        },
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-stream@0.1.0": {
          "stream-browserify": "npm:stream-browserify@1.0.0"
        },
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-url@0.1.0": {
          "url": "npm:url@0.10.3"
        },
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0": {
          "util": "npm:util@0.10.3"
        },
        "github:jspm/nodelibs-vm@0.1.0": {
          "vm-browserify": "npm:vm-browserify@0.0.4"
        },
        "npm:assert@1.4.1": {
          "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0",
          "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
          "util": "npm:util@0.10.3"
        },
        "npm:aurelia-binding@1.0.3": {
          "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.0.0"
        },
        "npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.0": {
          "aurelia-event-aggregator": "npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-framework": "npm:aurelia-framework@1.0.2",
          "aurelia-history": "npm:aurelia-history@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-history-browser": "npm:aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-loader-default": "npm:aurelia-loader-default@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-logging-console": "npm:aurelia-logging-console@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-pal-browser": "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-polyfills": "npm:aurelia-polyfills@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-router": "npm:aurelia-router@1.0.2",
          "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.1",
          "aurelia-templating-binding": "npm:aurelia-templating-binding@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-templating-resources": "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-templating-router": "npm:aurelia-templating-router@1.0.0"
        },
        "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0": {
          "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0"
        },
        "npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.0": {
          "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0"
        },
        "npm:aurelia-framework@1.0.2": {
          "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.0.3",
          "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-loader": "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.1"
        },
        "npm:aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0": {
          "aurelia-history": "npm:aurelia-history@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0"
        },
        "npm:aurelia-loader-default@1.0.0": {
          "aurelia-loader": "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0"
        },
        "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0": {
          "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0"
        },
        "npm:aurelia-logging-console@1.0.0": {
          "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0"
        },
        "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0": {
          "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0"
        },
        "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@1.0.0": {
          "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0"
        },
        "npm:aurelia-polyfills@1.0.0": {
          "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0"
        },
        "npm:aurelia-route-recognizer@1.0.0": {
          "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0"
        },
        "npm:aurelia-router@1.0.2": {
          "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-event-aggregator": "npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-history": "npm:aurelia-history@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-route-recognizer": "npm:aurelia-route-recognizer@1.0.0"
        },
        "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.0.0": {
          "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0"
        },
        "npm:aurelia-templating-binding@1.0.0": {
          "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.0.3",
          "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.1"
        },
        "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0": {
          "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.0.3",
          "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-loader": "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.1"
        },
        "npm:aurelia-templating-router@1.0.0": {
          "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-router": "npm:aurelia-router@1.0.2",
          "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.1"
        },
        "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.1": {
          "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.0.3",
          "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-loader": "npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-pal": "npm:aurelia-pal@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@1.0.0",
          "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.0.0"
        },
        "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.38": {
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
        },
        "npm:benchmark@1.0.0": {
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
        },
        "npm:better-assert@1.0.2": {
          "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0",
          "callsite": "npm:callsite@1.0.0",
          "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
        },
        "npm:buffer@3.6.0": {
          "base64-js": "npm:base64-js@0.0.8",
          "child_process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-child_process@0.1.0",
          "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
          "ieee754": "npm:ieee754@1.1.6",
          "isarray": "npm:isarray@1.0.0",
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
        },
        "npm:core-js@1.2.7": {
          "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
          "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
          "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.2"
        },
        "npm:core-util-is@1.0.2": {
          "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0"
        },
        "npm:d3-brush@1.0.2": {
          "d3-dispatch": "npm:d3-dispatch@1.0.1",
          "d3-drag": "npm:d3-drag@1.0.1",
          "d3-interpolate": "npm:d3-interpolate@1.1.1",
          "d3-selection": "npm:d3-selection@1.0.2",
          "d3-transition": "npm:d3-transition@1.0.1"
        },
        "npm:d3-chord@1.0.2": {
          "d3-array": "npm:d3-array@1.0.1",
          "d3-path": "npm:d3-path@1.0.1"
        },
        "npm:d3-drag@1.0.1": {
          "d3-dispatch": "npm:d3-dispatch@1.0.1",
          "d3-selection": "npm:d3-selection@1.0.2"
        },
        "npm:d3-dsv@1.0.1": {
          "rw": "npm:rw@1.3.2"
        },
        "npm:d3-force@1.0.2": {
          "d3-collection": "npm:d3-collection@1.0.1",
          "d3-dispatch": "npm:d3-dispatch@1.0.1",
          "d3-quadtree": "npm:d3-quadtree@1.0.1",
          "d3-timer": "npm:d3-timer@1.0.2",
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
        },
        "npm:d3-geo@1.2.3": {
          "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
          "d3-array": "npm:d3-array@1.0.1"
        },
        "npm:d3-interpolate@1.1.1": {
          "d3-color": "npm:d3-color@1.0.1"
        },
        "npm:d3-request@1.0.2": {
          "d3-collection": "npm:d3-collection@1.0.1",
          "d3-dispatch": "npm:d3-dispatch@1.0.1",
          "d3-dsv": "npm:d3-dsv@1.0.1",
          "xmlhttprequest": "npm:xmlhttprequest@1.8.0"
        },
        "npm:d3-scale@1.0.3": {
          "d3-array": "npm:d3-array@1.0.1",
          "d3-collection": "npm:d3-collection@1.0.1",
          "d3-color": "npm:d3-color@1.0.1",
          "d3-format": "npm:d3-format@1.0.2",
          "d3-interpolate": "npm:d3-interpolate@1.1.1",
          "d3-time": "npm:d3-time@1.0.2",
          "d3-time-format": "npm:d3-time-format@2.0.2"
        },
        "npm:d3-shape@1.0.2": {
          "d3-path": "npm:d3-path@1.0.1"
        },
        "npm:d3-time-format@2.0.2": {
          "d3-time": "npm:d3-time@1.0.2"
        },
        "npm:d3-transition@1.0.1": {
          "d3-color": "npm:d3-color@1.0.1",
          "d3-dispatch": "npm:d3-dispatch@1.0.1",
          "d3-ease": "npm:d3-ease@1.0.1",
          "d3-interpolate": "npm:d3-interpolate@1.1.1",
          "d3-selection": "npm:d3-selection@1.0.2",
          "d3-timer": "npm:d3-timer@1.0.2"
        },
        "npm:d3-zoom@1.0.3": {
          "d3-dispatch": "npm:d3-dispatch@1.0.1",
          "d3-drag": "npm:d3-drag@1.0.1",
          "d3-interpolate": "npm:d3-interpolate@1.1.1",
          "d3-selection": "npm:d3-selection@1.0.2",
          "d3-transition": "npm:d3-transition@1.0.1"
        },
        "npm:d3@4.2.2": {
          "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
          "d3-array": "npm:d3-array@1.0.1",
          "d3-axis": "npm:d3-axis@1.0.3",
          "d3-brush": "npm:d3-brush@1.0.2",
          "d3-chord": "npm:d3-chord@1.0.2",
          "d3-collection": "npm:d3-collection@1.0.1",
          "d3-color": "npm:d3-color@1.0.1",
          "d3-dispatch": "npm:d3-dispatch@1.0.1",
          "d3-drag": "npm:d3-drag@1.0.1",
          "d3-dsv": "npm:d3-dsv@1.0.1",
          "d3-ease": "npm:d3-ease@1.0.1",
          "d3-force": "npm:d3-force@1.0.2",
          "d3-format": "npm:d3-format@1.0.2",
          "d3-geo": "npm:d3-geo@1.2.3",
          "d3-hierarchy": "npm:d3-hierarchy@1.0.2",
          "d3-interpolate": "npm:d3-interpolate@1.1.1",
          "d3-path": "npm:d3-path@1.0.1",
          "d3-polygon": "npm:d3-polygon@1.0.1",
          "d3-quadtree": "npm:d3-quadtree@1.0.1",
          "d3-queue": "npm:d3-queue@3.0.2",
          "d3-random": "npm:d3-random@1.0.1",
          "d3-request": "npm:d3-request@1.0.2",
          "d3-scale": "npm:d3-scale@1.0.3",
          "d3-selection": "npm:d3-selection@1.0.2",
          "d3-shape": "npm:d3-shape@1.0.2",
          "d3-time": "npm:d3-time@1.0.2",
          "d3-time-format": "npm:d3-time-format@2.0.2",
          "d3-timer": "npm:d3-timer@1.0.2",
          "d3-transition": "npm:d3-transition@1.0.1",
          "d3-voronoi": "npm:d3-voronoi@1.0.2",
          "d3-zoom": "npm:d3-zoom@1.0.3",
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
        },
        "npm:debug@2.2.0": {
          "ms": "npm:ms@0.7.1"
        },
        "npm:engine.io-client@1.6.11": {
          "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
          "component-emitter": "npm:component-emitter@1.1.2",
          "component-inherit": "npm:component-inherit@0.0.3",
          "debug": "npm:debug@2.2.0",
          "engine.io-parser": "npm:engine.io-parser@1.2.4",
          "has-cors": "npm:has-cors@1.1.0",
          "indexof": "npm:indexof@0.0.1",
          "parsejson": "npm:parsejson@0.0.1",
          "parseqs": "npm:parseqs@0.0.2",
          "parseuri": "npm:parseuri@0.0.4",
          "yeast": "npm:yeast@0.1.2"
        },
        "npm:engine.io-parser@1.2.4": {
          "after": "npm:after@0.8.1",
          "arraybuffer.slice": "npm:arraybuffer.slice@0.0.6",
          "base64-arraybuffer": "npm:base64-arraybuffer@0.1.2",
          "blob": "npm:blob@0.0.4",
          "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
          "has-binary": "npm:has-binary@0.1.6",
          "utf8": "npm:utf8@2.1.0"
        },
        "npm:has-binary@0.1.6": {
          "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
          "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
          "isarray": "npm:isarray@0.0.1"
        },
        "npm:has-binary@0.1.7": {
          "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
          "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
          "isarray": "npm:isarray@0.0.1"
        },
        "npm:https-browserify@0.0.0": {
          "http": "github:jspm/nodelibs-http@1.7.1"
        },
        "npm:inherits@2.0.1": {
          "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0"
        },
        "npm:parsejson@0.0.1": {
          "better-assert": "npm:better-assert@1.0.2"
        },
        "npm:parseqs@0.0.2": {
          "better-assert": "npm:better-assert@1.0.2"
        },
        "npm:parseuri@0.0.4": {
          "better-assert": "npm:better-assert@1.0.2"
        },
        "npm:path-browserify@0.0.0": {
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
        },
        "npm:process@0.11.9": {
          "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0",
          "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
          "vm": "github:jspm/nodelibs-vm@0.1.0"
        },
        "npm:punycode@1.3.2": {
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
        },
        "npm:readable-stream@1.1.14": {
          "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
          "core-util-is": "npm:core-util-is@1.0.2",
          "events": "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1",
          "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
          "isarray": "npm:isarray@0.0.1",
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
          "stream-browserify": "npm:stream-browserify@1.0.0",
          "string_decoder": "npm:string_decoder@0.10.31"
        },
        "npm:rw@1.3.2": {
          "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
          "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
        },
        "npm:socket.io-client@1.4.8": {
          "backo2": "npm:backo2@1.0.2",
          "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
          "component-bind": "npm:component-bind@1.0.0",
          "component-emitter": "npm:component-emitter@1.2.0",
          "debug": "npm:debug@2.2.0",
          "engine.io-client": "npm:engine.io-client@1.6.11",
          "has-binary": "npm:has-binary@0.1.7",
          "indexof": "npm:indexof@0.0.1",
          "object-component": "npm:object-component@0.0.3",
          "parseuri": "npm:parseuri@0.0.4",
          "socket.io-parser": "npm:socket.io-parser@2.2.6",
          "to-array": "npm:to-array@0.1.4"
        },
        "npm:socket.io-parser@2.2.6": {
          "benchmark": "npm:benchmark@1.0.0",
          "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
          "component-emitter": "npm:component-emitter@1.1.2",
          "debug": "npm:debug@2.2.0",
          "isarray": "npm:isarray@0.0.1",
          "json3": "npm:json3@3.3.2"
        },
        "npm:stream-browserify@1.0.0": {
          "events": "github:jspm/nodelibs-events@0.1.1",
          "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
          "readable-stream": "npm:readable-stream@1.1.14"
        },
        "npm:string_decoder@0.10.31": {
          "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0"
        },
        "npm:url@0.10.3": {
          "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0",
          "punycode": "npm:punycode@1.3.2",
          "querystring": "npm:querystring@0.2.0",
          "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@0.1.0"
        },
        "npm:utf8@2.1.0": {
          "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.2"
        },
        "npm:util@0.10.3": {
          "inherits": "npm:inherits@2.0.1",
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
        },
        "npm:vm-browserify@0.0.4": {
          "indexof": "npm:indexof@0.0.1"
        },
        "npm:xmlhttprequest@1.8.0": {
          "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
          "child_process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-child_process@0.1.0",
          "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
          "http": "github:jspm/nodelibs-http@1.7.1",
          "https": "github:jspm/nodelibs-https@0.1.0",
          "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
          "url": "github:jspm/nodelibs-url@0.1.0"
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't a JSPM issue, but the d3 API changed.

The format.parse method has also been removed in favor of separate d3.timeParse, d3.utcParse and d3.isoParse parser constructors. Thus, this code in 3.x:

```
var parseTime = d3.time.format("%c").parse;
```

Can be rewritten in 4.0 as:

```
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%c");
```

https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#time-formats-d3-time-format

By default it installs version 4.

```
import { timeFormat } from 'd3';

    export class Welcome {

      attached() {
        var formatMonth = timeFormat("%B"),
            formatDay = timeFormat("%A"),
            date = new Date(2014, 4, 1); 

            console.log(formatMonth(date)); // "May"
            console.log(formatDay(date)); // "Thursday"
      }

    }
```

works